# How to install gedit using yum

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, installation, yum

I'm trying to install gedit on an Amazon EC2 instance running Redhat 4.4.4-13.  I thought it would be as easy as

```
sudo yum install gedit
```

But that just gives me:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                             | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package gedit available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Trying "yum repolist all" gives me this:

```
repo id                          repo name                        status
amzn-main                        amzn-main-Base                   enabled: 2,463
amzn-main-debuginfo              amzn-main-debuginfo              disabled
amzn-main-nosrc                  amzn-main-nosrc                  disabled
amzn-updates                     amzn-updates-Base                enabled:    86
amzn-updates-debuginfo           amzn-updates-debuginfo           disabled
amzn-updates-nosrc               amzn-updates-nosrc               disabled
repolist: 2,549
```

So it looks as though this machine doesn't have any of the usual repositories, including those with gedit. How do I install those?  I can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: are you using some sort of x11 or vnc connection to the box ?

Comment: I'm logging in with straight SSH, but would like to use an X11 connection to run gedit remotely.  Much easier to use than vi...

Comment: I've just been encountering a similar issue on Amazon WorkSpaces AL2 hosts. In that instance I found `pluma` to be a good alternative to `gedit`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't appear to be running Red Hat, but [Amazon Linux](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/). Since this is designed to be a server instance, they may have chosen not to provide desktop tools such as `gedit`.

Comment: This was the problem.  I can see why most EC2 users wouldn't need tools like gedit, but I was surprised how difficult is was to install it.

Comment: to be honest, nano, pico, joe, mcedit (part of the mc package), or vi aren't very hard to use. In particular, mcedit you can use the F-keys. I'd *highly* suggest learning at least one, as needing gedit is going to cripple you on servers.

Comment: I can get around in nano and vi, but sometimes it's really nice to be able to use the mouse and copy-paste.  gedit is my fallback tool for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

This works in CentOS so it should be fine in RedHat.

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
vi name.repo
```

Then inside of that add the following:

```
[nameofrepo]
name=Description of the repo you're adding
baseurl=URL of the repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=RPM GPD Key
```

Then do a rpm --import of the GPD key URL and you should be set.